# How to simplyfy the expression ${(m+k-1 \text{ mod } k) + 1}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$m$ takes values from 1 to an even number $M$ and $k = M/2$. This expression ${(m+k-1 \text{ mod } k) + 1}$ gives the repeated sequence of numbers from 1 to k. How can I further simply the expression to give the same repeated sequence?

For example M = 24 the expression gives the sequence

1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $k\equiv0\bmod k$, so in the end we get $(m-1)\bmod k+1$ (assuming the computing definition of $\bmod$).

Comment: $m \mod k$ gives      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11     0. the values at m = 12 and 24 is zero not 12

Comment: $m-1 \mod k +1$ gives the same but I am not sure we can further simplify.